# NodeJS - Trying to render index.ejs file, but still only servers index.html that is in my public folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

The code below still serves the `index.html` page that's in the `public` folder, but I want to render `index.ejs`. I followed the video example so I'm not sure why he's able to render the `ejs` file whereas I'm still only seeing the `index.html` file.

The video example I am using seems to be the same. My `package.json` file has `"main": "app.js"`.

Here is the video example link, and code below:
https://youtu.be/gnsO8-xJ8rs?t=28m12s

```
//View Engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

//Body Parser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : false}));

//Set Static path
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//Routes
app.get('/', (req, res) => {//homepage represented by the single slash
  res.render('index');
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('server started on port 3000...');
});
```

I noticed that if I comment out

```
//Routes
app.get('/', (req, res) => {//homepage represented by the single slash
  res.render('index');
});
```

then the ejs file is rendered and served.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: My assumption would be that its because of your static path uncomment the routes and include the file path to your directory e.g.`./../views/index.ejs`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that EJS by default looks into '**Views**' folder

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
```

You can specify the file path to look in your folder as **Views** change this to your **public** folder and It will be up and running.